# Kivy unable to import Camera

Tags: python, kivy

I'm attempting to get my webcam on my macbook pro (OSX 10.8) to stream live video or take screencaps with kivy / python.

I attempted using this application:

http://karanbalkar.com/2012/10/tutorial-6-working-with-camera-in-kivy/

Trying to just do the following import:

```
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
```

I receive:

```
[DEBUG  ] [Camera      ] Ignored <opencv> (import error)
[CRITICAL] [Camera      ] Unable to find any valuable Camera provider at all!
```

Any help is greatly appreciated here.
-Jon K.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind.  I was able to figure out the issue.  It seems you need to add gst-python and opencv on your own.  Also, once I had added them they were associated with the wrong version of Python.  I was able to clean it up and can now run the following with no issue:

```
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
```

Answer (score 0):

I check the above tutorial and it works for me. To make it working i install these packages

```
python-setuptools python-pygame python-opengl \
python-gst0.10 python-enchant gstreamer0.10-plugins-good python-dev \
build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev cython
```

and then install or update kivy.

Once you install kivy than just check it out in python shell

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import kivy
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.7.1
```

if it shows the same result than change this line in tutorial code

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.1') #change kivy version same as it shows in above import.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  Are these packages only for ubuntu?  I'm working in OSX and I've only been able to add some of the packages.python-gst0.10 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good python-dev \
build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-de seem to all be for ubuntu

Comment: Ok, i'll see that and have found the second import part of kivy in python shell? and make sure that you haven't miss any instructions over here http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-macosx.html

Comment: Yes, I followed all of those instructions.  I'm using Kivy v1.8.0-dev.  I'm assuming there is some camera dependency I'm missing.

Comment: It's now 2019 and this kind of sloppy code and indifference toward wasting others' time appears to still be present/evident in several of the examples.